# Good practice to use global objects in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, nw.js

I'm creating desktop app using [nw.js](https://nwjs.io/) framework with angular. In my controllers, services etc. i often use `Node.js` modules like this:

```
module.exports = function(ngModule) {
    ngModule.service('User', ['$q', function ($q) {
        var self = this;
        var fs = require('fs');
        var path = require('path');
        var gui = require('nw.gui');
    }]);
};
```

Is this a good practice ? Or maybe better create some service or put modules in $`rootScope` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally `require`s should not remain within service constructor (unless they are conditional):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var gui = require('nw.gui');

ngModule.service('User', ['$q', function ($q) {
  ...
}]);
```

The code above will require to use packages like `proxyquire` to mock Node modules and test the service in isolation.

DI is supposed to introduce additional flexibility and testability to the application. Having the dependencies in separate module that can be easily stubbed is generally preferable way to handle this:

```
angular.module('node', [])
.constant('gui', require('nw.gui'))
...

...

angular.module('app', ['node'])
.service('User', function ($q, gui, ...) {
  ...
});
```